# Trying to replace a single switch to a double switch with only 1 black wire

Tags: electrical

[image: unused ceiling box with black, white, and ground...all capped[![Wall box with light switch and outlet. The yellow cable is the new fan cable. It is capped as not attached to the circuit yet.]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Egf.jpg)I have installed an exhaust fan in my bathroom.  There is an existing switch operating the light.  I want to hook up the fan to this box using a double switch. My issue is there are only 3 wires: white, black, and ground. There once was a ceiling light which was replaced with wall lights on both side of the medicine cabinet.  The light box is still in the ceiling with live wires capped.  Can anyone explain how to best repair this? Ideally, I would like to disconnect the ceiling box altogether and just have the light and fan work from the single box using a double switch.

Comment: Can you provide photos of the boxes involved?

Comment: your description is unclear. You just installed a fan, are there wires to it? Where do they go? What wires are in the unused ceiling box?

Comment: The unused box has white, black, and ground wires.  There is a new cable running from the fan to the wall box, but not attached to the switch, just capped and taped at the moment. I forgot to mention that the wall box also houses an outlet.

Comment: You might want to consider having the work done by an electrician or handyman who knows the electrical code.  It sounds like you may need to run some wire.  There are code requirements that aren't always obvious or intuitive.  If you don't follow code and there is a future problem, like an electrical fire, your insurance won't cover it.  And if non-compliant work is visible, like in the attic, it may fail a home inspection when you go to sell.

Comment: Is the white cable on the left, does that go to the *currently operating* light?  Or does it go to the old light location?  The switch which operates the current lights - was it on the left in this box?  Where does the current light get its power?